# Is there a Raspberry Pi B+ GPIO header footprint for kicad?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, raspberry-pi, kicad, footprint

I attempted to make my own using the ModEdit utility in kicad but I'm still having issues adjusting it to the grid even though I followed the standard 0.1'' pitch.  It still seems to be off.  Is there a footprint available for the 2x20 pinout on this board?

Comment: Yes the footprint is available.

Comment: @Dzarda I am unable to locate it.  Do you know where I might find it?

Comment: That should be a standard post header footprint, perhaps called something like "header2x20" (but probably no reference to "Raspberry").

Comment: @PeterBennett That's the first thing I tried to use, it did not appear to be the correct size.

Comment: @wes .1 inch headers are like the most common footprint there is. It _has to_ be present. And they are dead easy. Pins 2.54mm apart. That's it.

Comment: @Dzarda Maybe I'm not scaling correctly?  I laid the generic pinout down, ported, and then printed the gerber.  Still appeared to be too small.

Comment: @wes It must be a scaling issue, somewhere in your process.

Answer (score 6):

The Raspberry Pi B+ GPIO header is a standard 2x20 pin straight header.

The footprint for that part is the "Pin_Header_Straight_2x20" footprint in the "Pin_Headers" library that comes with with the current version of KiCAD.

The earlier Raspberry Pi B+ GPIO header is a standard 2x13 pin straight header.
The footprint for that part is the "Pin_Header_Straight_2x13" in the same "Pin_Headers" library.

All these parts have a 0.1" pitch -- in other words, the center of each pin is on a 0.1 inch (2.54 mm) grid.

Several inkjet printers are notorious for printing things with an X scale that is slightly off and a Y scale that is slightly worse.
You may find the KiCAD "Measurement_Scales" library useful in figuring out where things go wrong.
There's a pretty good chance that your Gerber files are actually perfect, and parts will fit perfectly on the boards made from those Gerbers, even if the parts don't seem to line up exactly perfectly on the rough-draft paper printouts from an inkjet printer.